# ERROR com.websudos.phantom - Batch too large

Tags: scala, cassandra-2.1, phantom-dsl

I am getting the following error:

```
22:24:34.419 [run-main-0] DEBUG com.websudos.phantom - Executing query: com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement@3f4f5b68
22:24:34.426 [pool-15-thread-3] ERROR com.websudos.phantom - Batch too large
[error] (run-main-0) com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Batch too large
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Batch too large
```

Have re-run the code and getting this error at the following point each time:

```
cqlsh> select count(*) from superchain.blocks  limit 1000000;

 count
-------
 51728

(1 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key
```

Thanks in advance for any insights.

+++ UPDATES +++

So the offending code is

```
//This file is Database.scala
class Database(val keyspace: KeySpaceDef) extends DatabaseImpl(keyspace) {
  def insertBlock(block: Block) = {
  //should note here that have also tried Batch.unlogged to same effect
    Batch.logged
      .add(ChainDatabase.block.insertNewRecord(block))
      .future()
  }

  def insertTransaction(tx: Transaction) = {
  //should note here that have also tried Batch.unlogged to same effect
    Batch.logged
      .add(ChainDatabase.tx.insertNewTransaction(tx))
      .future()
  }

  object block extends BlockTable with keyspace.Connector

  object tx extends TransactionTable with keyspace.Connector


}

object ChainDatabase extends Database(Config.keySpaceDefinition)
```

The following shows the inserting functions for Transaction and there is similar code for the Block.

Have tried to follow

https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e#.7zdd0qopv

&&

https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Batch-statements

But am still struggling to find an implementation that does not lead to the `Batch too large` errors.

```
//This file is Transaction.scala
abstract class TransactionTable extends TransactionColumnFamily with RootConnector {

  override val tableName = "transactions"

  def insertNew(tx: Transaction): Future[ResultSet] = insertNewTransaction(tx).future()

  def insertNewTransaction(tx: Transaction) = {
    insert
      .value(_.txid, tx.txid)
      .value(_.version, tx.version)
      .value(_.locktime, tx.locktime)
      .value(_.vout, tx.vout)
      .value(_.vin, tx.vin)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is not because of the size of the table, but because of the number of queries in the batch. You can run at most 100 queries simultaneously in any given batch.

At the same time, you are almost 99% using the less optimal approach here, since you never really want so many queries in a single batch. As Thiago suggests, batches are designed to guarantee atomicity, and not to optimise performance.

If you want to simply do parallel queries, simply use `Future.sequence`, which will use a fork join pool kind of approach to paralellize the operations.

**The error is from Cassandra**, not from phantom. It won't matter what kind of approach you use on the client, the batch size is capped.

```
// Assuming you have a list of queries:
val execution = Future.sequence(queries map (_.future())
```

Hope this helps!

**Update**

Let's say you have a list of transactions.

```
val list: List[Transaction] = ..
// all you need is
Future.sequence(list.map(tr => database.transactionTable.insertNew(tr))
```

This will produce a future that will complete when all the underlying futures complete, effectively giving you a return type: `Future[List[ResultSet]]` from your original `List[Future[ResultSet]]`.

Comment: @thiago-pereira & flavian : have updated the question some more in the hopes a specific example of "If you want to simply do parallel queries, simply use Future.sequence, which will use a fork join pool kind of approach to paralellize the operations."

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have misunderstood the purpose of batches in Cassandra.

Actually they are for atomicity not to run several queries to be "faster".

A well explanation can be found here:

https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/

Answer (score 1):

As others had said, your first error message is from a BATCH statement that is very large. BATCH statements are not designed for batch inserts as you would think of in a traditional relational database. BATCH statements are only useful when ATOMICALLY inserting data across several denormalized tables, or using an UNLOGGED BATCH for inserting data under the same partition key.

[Batch statements should NOT be used as an optimization technique](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/), as they are not designed for speed and will in fact hurt your performance.

In the end this is an ERROR message since the Cassandra Client Driver is trying to protect the cluster from a very large BATCH statement that can (and will) bring down nodes in your cluster.

Secondly, you point out that running a `SELECT count(*) FROM table;` is giving you the warning:

`Aggregation query used without partition key`.

Using `count(*)` is without specifying a partition key is an [antipattern](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/counting-key-in-cassandra/). For similar reasons as above, it can negatively affect the stability of your cluster.

Lastly I suspect that somewhere in your Cassandra DSL library (not familiar with Phantom-DSL) that it's doing a BATCH where you don't expect it, or you may be consciously using BATCH without fully understanding it's appropriate usage. I know that in spring-data they use a BATCH when you do an insert of a list of items (which is a terrible antipattern) which could result in a similar error.